# Sysprep Fatal Error Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

We're Using HP Workstation ELitebook Folio 9470m Windows 7 Professional with Images

Also we're using `Trend Micro`. When we set up a Image it take's as usual the SID of the Imagepc and whe have to change it because of Trend Micro Lizenzes.
So we wan't to change them with `Sysprep`.

When I Start Sysprep there is a Error i can enter with OK and Sysprep cloeses:

> Fatal Error on System preparation.

Eventviewer:

> Event ID 3 system Failure Microsoft Security Client OOBE
>   is closed because of the failure 0xC0000000D

I tried:

- Deactivate Windows Media Player Network Service
- Change the Registry from Sysprep (SYSWOW64 -> System32) (Generalize / Cleanup / Specialize) http://www.lernschmiede.de/ie10-sysprepworkaround-ist-da

I'm sorry for my bad english. Thats the information i see and i can give. 
Is There any workaround for this Sysprep Failure on Win 7?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide any information on the fatal error itself.

Comment: When i Start Sysprep there is a window which means that there is a Fatal Error on System preparation. There i just can press OK and Sysprep closes. on Eventviewer there is a Event ID 3 system Failure which means that the Microsoft Security Client OOBE is closed because of the failure 0xC0000000D

Comment: You will want to update the actual question with ALL information you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more common causes of Sysprep failure is when security software conflicts with the generalization process. You may want to attempt disabling Trend Micro before you run Sysprep. [For Trend Micro Titanium there are instructions provided by Trend Micro here](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/solution/en-us/1058376.aspx).